# Serving absolute path of the directory which isn't relative to the directory from where I launch my node process isn't working

Tags: node.js, express

I ran node process of my 'app.js' file specifying 'public' directory (relative to the same directory) in my code and it worked well.
By creating a file (test.js) in /tmp/test/ and writing exact same code as 'app.js' file got no response as I put the absolute file path. 
Note: There's a html file inside 'public'

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if your folder is like ./app.js ./tmp/test/test.js ./public then in your test file you have to write: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')));`